# Calling 3 functions recursively in flutter app without slowing the application

Tags: flutter

I called 3 function in main widget because of that app is taking too much time to load data from firebase and also the whole app gets hang. Is there any other way to call these 3 function and also working that functionality as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rigato/global.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:rigato/ClientsDetail/ClientDetailTab.dart';
import 'package:rigato/localization/app_translations.dart';

class Clients1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final searchText;

  Clients1({this.searchText});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Clients();
}

class _Clients extends State<Clients1> {
  ScrollController controller;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  //Function for call
  void _call(String number) async {
    if (await canLaunch(number)) {
      await launch(number);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $number';
    }
  }

  //Function for Email
  void _sendEmail(String emailAddress) async {
    if (await canLaunch(emailAddress)) {
      await launch(emailAddress);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $emailAddress';
    }
  }

  // Function for make list according search data
  List<DocumentSnapshot> initialData = List<DocumentSnapshot>();

  getSearchText() {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> tempList = List<DocumentSnapshot>();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialData.length; i++) {
      var name = initialData[i]["nameFs"] + initialData[i]["nameLs"];
      var city = initialData[i]["city"] == null ? "" : initialData[i]["city"];
      if (name.toLowerCase().contains(widget.searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
          initialData[i]["idOrder"]
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(widget.searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
          city.toLowerCase().contains(widget.searchText.toLowerCase())) {
        tempList.add(initialData[i]);
      }
    }
    clientData = tempList;
    setState(() {});
  }

  int sequenceIndex;
  String sequenceName;

  getStatus() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        sequenceIndex = prefs.getInt("previousIndex");
      });
    }
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('sequence').getDocuments();
    for (int i = 0; i < clientData.length; i++) {
      if (sequenceIndex == snapshot.documents[i].data['index']) {
        setState(() {
          sequenceName = snapshot.documents[i].data['sequenceName'];
        });
      }
//      print("this is sequence name ${sequenceName}");
    }
  }

  var clientData;

  bool isGet = false;

  getData() async {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection('clients');
    QuerySnapshot collectionSnapshot = await collectionReference.getDocuments();
    clientData = collectionSnapshot.documents;
    initialData = collectionSnapshot.documents;
//    initialData = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < clientData.length; i++) {
      print("log of sequence name ${sequenceName}");
      if (sequenceName == clientData[i]['sequenceStatus']) {
        print("this is clientdata${clientData[i]['sequenceStatus']}");
        initialData.add(clientData[i]);
      }
    }
    print("this is initial data ${initialData}");

    setState(() {
      isGet = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getSearchText();
    getData();
    getStatus();

    if (clientData.isEmpty) {
      clientData = initialData;
    }
    return isGet == false
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appColor),
          ))
        : Container(
            color: offWhite,
            child: Scrollbar(
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                itemCount: clientData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        prefs.setString(
                            'clientId', clientData[index].documentID);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                ClientDetailTab(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      onLongPress: () {
                        AlertBox().show(
                            context,
                            AppTranslations.of(context).text("alert"),
                            AppTranslations.of(context)
                                .text("do-you-want-to-delete-this-record?"),
                            (value) {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          Firestore.instance
                              .collection('clients')
                              .document(
                                clientData[index].documentID,
                              )
                              .delete()
                              .catchError((e) {});
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          color: clientData[index]['sector'] == "all"
                              ? yellow
                              : offWhite,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon:
                                          Icon(Icons.star_border, color: grey),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        LightText(
                                          text: clientData[index]['nameFs'] ==
                                                      null ||
                                                  clientData[index]['nameLs'] ==
                                                      null
                                              ? ""
                                              : clientData[index]['nameFs'] +
                                                  " " +
                                                  clientData[index]['nameLs'],
                                        ),
                                        LightText(
                                            text: clientData[index]['idOrder']),
                                        LightText(
                                            text: clientData[index]['city'] ==
                                                    null
                                                ? ""
                                                : clientData[index]['city']),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.call,
                                          color: grey,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          String mob =
                                              clientData[index]['mobileOne'];
                                          _call('tel:$mob');
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: grey),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          String email =
                                              clientData[index]['emailOne'];
                                          _sendEmail('mailto:$email');
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, top: 0),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )));
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getSearchText();
    getData();
    getStatus();
}
```

These are 3 functions that I am calling recursively to get data from firebase. and search functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the app from freezing you should create an isolate using the ['compute' function,](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) this will process the data separately from the main thread. Example  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Example provided in the link

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}
```